# Mac kernel panic, now Android Studio project won't run

Tags: macos, android-studio, gradle, kernel, panic

I've been happily using Android Studio for months. Today for the first time when I hit "Clean Project" the Mac had a kernel panic, and after restart Android Studio was apparently corrupted. Got all kinds of messages about plugins being disabled.

I reinstalled it but now the .gradle folder and all its subfolders in the Project view are shown in red, which I assume means trouble, and the green Run arrow at the top of the window is grayed out. How do I fix this? I've tried Rebuild Project but it didn't work.

The Git server that hosts the project seems (hopefully) to be OK.

[Update] The observed behavior was apparently due to the loss of Run Configurations in the crash. Re-creating a Default configuration enabled the app to run.

Comment: I now see that the red .gradle folder may not necessarily be a problem; it goes away if you uncheck "Show Excluded Files" in the Project settings. Interesting question though how this setting apparently got changed by the kernel panic/reinstall. Apparently all my Run configurations were lost in the crash; I recreated a Default one and am able to run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel panic apparently clobbered Android Studio's Run configurations. Re-creating a Default configuration enabled the project to run.